# How to Align a div middle inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was create a div and another div inside of the div. I want these dot lines  **...**  should be middle of the parent div (Horizontally and Vertically). Please help me. Thank you.

```html
<div class = "test" style = "width: 32px; height: 22px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;">
 <div style = "display: inline-block;">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At first, you dont need another div for that. Use text-align:center + line-height + padding

Comment: If you still need a div use left:50%; margin-left: halfwidth in px

Comment: @Jonasw Oh! good. That's cool. its working. Thank you.

Comment: i add it as an answer soon, so that you can check it

Comment: @Jonasw Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

One possibility (and there are many) could be to use [CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

You can use the `justify-content` property to define aligment along the main axis and the `align-items` property to define how flex items are laid out along the cross axis.

You `.test` container would looks like this:

```
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can check an example on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybwy5xpq/1/).

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use table-cell on your parent element and inline-block on the child and add vertical-align: middle to parent element:

```
<div class = "test" style = "width: 32px; height: 22px; display: table-cell; border: 1px solid; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style = "display: inline-block;">...</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkfr6ar1/

Comment: But this is not working.

Comment: i modified the code you need to add vertical-align: middle to parent element